# Object.setPrototypeOf: how to get the original prototype name?

Tags: javascript

I have changed a class instance's prototype in the constructor. The new prototype is `Object`'s instance. So when I try to get the new constructor name with `self.__proto__.constructor.name` it returns `Object` which is right.
But somehow Chrome Devtools knows that `self` is still an instance of `Example`!
I remember that some things that inaccessible in JS is known to Chrome Devtools.
Is there any way in JS to retrieve the name of the object's original constructor like Chrome Devtools does?

Btw the code is pure experimental, not for production.

[image]

```js
const example = new function Example() {
    const self = Object.setPrototypeOf(this, {
        get name(){
            return self.__proto__.constructor.name;
        },
    });
};

console.log(example.name);
```