# Changed constructor function's 'prototype' property and two different reference method

Tags: javascript

```
//1)
function Rabbit() {}
Rabbit.prototype = {
  eats: true
};

let rabbit = new Rabbit();

Rabbit.prototype = {};

alert( rabbit.eats ); // true

//2)
function Rabbit() {}
Rabbit.prototype = {
  eats: true
};

let rabbit = new Rabbit();

Rabbit.prototype.eats = false;

alert( rabbit.eats ); // false
```

I expected 'false' in the 1) case..and contemplated about this mechanism and conclude something on my own. please see if I am right :)

Here's what happens:

1)
I define a Rabbit constructor function and set its prototype to an object with an eats property set to true.
I create a new instance of Rabbit using the new keyword and store it in the rabbit variable.
After that, I change the Rabbit.prototype to an empty object. However, this change does not affect the already created rabbit object.
When I try to access rabbit.eats, JavaScript first looks for the eats property directly on the rabbit object. Since the eats property is not found on the rabbit object, it goes up the prototype chain and finds it on the old prototype object { eats: true }. As a result, the alert shows true.

2)
the alert shows false.
In this case, I am modifying the eats property directly on the same object that the rabbit object points to through its [[Prototype]] link. So, the change is visible when accessing rabbit.eats.

Q)
I learned that objects assignning give varibles the address which is called object reference.
case 2) was easy to understand according to this. but I expected 'false' in the case 1).

My conclusion)
when I created 'Rabbit' function, the 'Rabbit.prototype' object is assigned to a memory. and in the case 2) 'Rabbit' and 'rabbit functions share the same memory address however, in the case 1), when I assign '{}' to the 'Rabbit.prototype'property. they find new memory address and assign this to it so the first object and second object that assigned to 'Rabbit.prototype' have diffrent memory address so that Rabbit.prototype refer to new memory address and rabbit.eats refere to old one.

Am I right?

Comment: Yep, your understanding is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first case works as it does because the prototype is copied into the created instance.

The interesting part is that when you overwrite a prototype completely all instances created with the previous prototype has now constructor `Object` so like the previous prototype is unbound from `Rabbit`. But the devtools knows the original constructor somehow. I've asked why and how to access it but no luck:

[Object.setPrototypeOf: how to get the original prototype name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76354986/object-setprototypeof-how-to-get-the-original-prototype-name)

```js
function Rabbit() {}

Rabbit.prototype = {
  eats: true
};

console.log('creating rabbit and rabbit2');
const rabbit = new Rabbit();
const rabbit2 = new Rabbit();

// you don't override prototype of the already created Rabbit instance
// since on `new` the prototype's reference was COPIED into the instance
console.log('overwriting Rabbit.prototype');
Rabbit.prototype = {};

console.log('constructor of rabbit is now:', rabbit.__proto__.constructor.name);

// you can check it:
console.log('Are prototypes equal (rabbit / Rabbit.prototype):', Object.getPrototypeOf(rabbit) === Rabbit.prototype);

console.log('Are prototypes equal (rabbit/rabbit2):', Object.getPrototypeOf(rabbit) === Object.getPrototypeOf(rabbit2));

console.log('rabbit.eats:', rabbit.eats ); // true

// you can manually copy the prototype
console.log('setting Rabbit.prototype back to rabbit');
Object.setPrototypeOf(rabbit, Rabbit.prototype);

console.log('rabbit.eats:', rabbit.eats ); // undefined
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for commenting :) but what I most wanted to know is this : when create new intance, instance refer to prototype property of cunstructor function. and it does as well when the prototype property has changed so that we can spare memory. but when prototype has totally changed which is like 'Rabbit.prototype = {};', does the computer allocate new memory so that instances can still use the previous prototype with no problem?

Comment: @LICON99 check `Are prototypes equal (rabbit/rabbit2)` - nothing happens with the old prototype, so now extra memory is allocated (my guess). You just allocate new memory for `{}`. Also updated my answer with some insights